# Finding multiple words in a string

Tags: javascript, string, search

I am trying to find multiple words in a comma separated log. I use the code below and this code can find one word at a time but not the 3 words together.

```
$log = "Left Side Turn, Left Side Road, No Turn, Left, Right Turn";
var currLog = $("#log").text();

var theName = "Left Side Road";      //this is what I'm searching for...

var currLogWords = currLog.split(/\b/);
        var hits = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < currlogWords.length; i++) {
            if (theName == currlogWords[i]) {
                hits.push(currlogWords[i]);
            }
        if (hits == 0) { do something } else { do other }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why your current code should work it has typo with `currLogWords` as `currlogWords` so it should give error like  `currlogWords is not defined`.

for search the complete string try this:

```
var log = "Left Side Turn, Left Side Road, No Turn, Left, Right Turn";
    var currLog = $("#log").text();

    var theName = "Left Side Road";      //this is what I'm searching for...

    var currLogWords = log.split(',');
            var hits = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < currLogWords.length; i++) {
                if (theName.trim() == currLogWords[i].trim()) {
                    hits.push(currLogWords[i]);
                }
            }
            if (hits == 0) { 
                console.log(hits.length); 
                } else { 
                    console.log(hits);
                    console.log(hits.length); 
                }
```

Comment: @Steve try this hope it will help.

Comment: thank you, your code worked! About currlogWords is not defined, you are right, I was changing some of the names and had a typo in the post...

Answer (score 0):

The parameter to the `split()` function determines how to split the contents of the string. Currently, you are using `\b` which chooses any word break (such as a space); just change it to use a comma, so that you only split along commas (you'll also want to remove leading and trailing whitespace after splitting so that you remove additional extra whitespace that occurs around each of the comma-separated items).